# How to create an Page Control in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create an Page Control in android....
I want to move from one page to another page, like the home screen in android device... it displays the current page by the 3 to 4 dots....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do exactly the same by doing something like:

```
int currentScreen = 1;

final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
                new MyGestureDetector());

findViewById(R.id.homescreen).setOnTouchListener(
                new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                            return true;
                        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                                || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                                ...detect scroll and change var...
```

As described here: [HorizontalScrollView within ScrollView Touch Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646028/android-horizontalscrollview-within-scrollview-touch-handling)

And here: [Android horizontal scrollview behave like iPhone (paging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595063/android-horizontal-scollview-behave-like-iphone-paging)

Answer (score 2):

ViewPager from Compatibility package is currently the best option.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewFlipper with animation to do this but for Touch event you have to crate Custom view.
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example