# How to add navigating arrow icons to HorizontalListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add arrow icon to this  [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) that show list has more items on right or left  like this image:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Too vague and not a real question per our guideline...have you tried any code?  Try google searching first...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

[Android horizontal scrollview behave like iPhone (paging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595063/android-horizontal-scollview-behave-like-iphone-paging)

Hope this helps.